# xargs with zgrep is giving the error

Tags: ls, xargs, zgrep

I have many gzipped files and I am trying to find some string pattern from the thousands of file but I am getting extra .gz while trying to zgrep it. Please refer the below, could you please advise. Thanks.

```
$ zcat abc.gz
1234^911^is^good
this^is^test

$ ls *.gz| xargs zgrep 911
gzip: abc.gz.gz: No such file or directory
```

Edit 1: @waltinator, thank you. In the echo it is showing the correct stuff.

```
$ ls *.gz| xargs echo zgrep 911
zgrep 911 abc.gz
$ ls *.gz| xargs zgrep 911
gzip: abc.gz.gz: No such file or directory
```

Edit2: find is giving the correct output

```
$ find . -name *.gz | xargs zgrep 911
1234^911^is^good
```

Comment: Debugging: replace `zgrep` with `echo zgrep` to see what's happening. Advice: don't parse `ls`, either `zgrep 911 *.gz` or use `find`.

Comment: Thank you find worked , any thoughts why ls is not working.